# How make a servlet print in html?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have an jsp page, *index*, this is it's code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="alteraSala.js"></script>
<div id="conteudo">
    <select id="sala">
        ...
    </select>
    <div id="resultado"></div>
</div>
```

My servlet is something like:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/hello")
public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
        out.println("<b>HELLO</b>");
    }
}
```

I've also got an AJAX file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sala').change(function (event) {
        var name = $('#sala').val();
        $.get('../EditarSala', {
            sala: name
        }, function (responseText) {
            $('#resultado').text(responseText);
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is that the output of the page is not:
**HELLO**
It's:
<b>HELLO</b>

## Edit:

Changed:

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
```

to:

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
```

Still isn't working

## Edit 2:

For some reason when I change the AJAX file from:

```
$('#resultado').text(responseText);
```

to:

```
$('#resultado').append(responseText);
```

It displays the text properly, but I can't use append.

Comment: Try setting response.setContentType("text/plain"); to response.setContentType("text/html");

Comment: @YogeshKumarGupta thx for your help! I did change but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't see any reason for this not to work.. cn u view source code of ur html page and paste here?

Comment: @YogeshKumarGupta what do you mean?

Comment: I tried your example on my local machine, and i could see that changing the contentType has resolved the issue.

Comment: @YogeshKumarGupta, thx for your help, but Hikmat already solved my problem, thx anyways :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use either `$.ajax()` or `$.post()` because you are also sending data.

Also your mistake is use `html()` not `text()` method of jquery.Because The `html()` method sets or returns the content (innerHTML) of the selected elements.But The `text()` method sets or returns the only text content of the selected elements.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sala').change(function (event) {
        var name = $('#sala').val();
        $.post('../EditarSala', {
            sala: name
        }, function (responseText) {
            $('#resultado').html(responseText);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: replace  `$('#resultado').text(responseText);` by  `$('#resultado').html(responseText);`

Answer (score 1):

Change `response.setContentType("text/plain");` to `response.setContentType("text/html");`

Comment: did you restarted the server after changing the servlet